# choosing the last element of a column composed by list of elements pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a pandas Dataframe like this:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame([
    (142, [1,2]),
    (144, 3),
    (144, 1),
    (142, 1),
    (142, [1,3]),
    (144, [1,5]),
    (142, 2)
], columns=['ID', 'Column_1'])
```

As you can see `Column_1` is column composed by single elements and list of elements.

My goal is create a new column which takes the last elements where `Column_1` is a list and the single value where is just one value, like this:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame([
    (142, [1,2] ,2),
    (144, 3 ,3),
    (144, 1 ,1),
    (142, 1 ,1),
    (142, [1,3] , 3),
    (144, [1,5] , 5),
    (142, 2)
], columns=['ID', 'Column_1' , 'new_column'])
```

Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: You must have made some sort of attempt, no? Please see here for an explanation of why I downvoted: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try `str` slice then `fillna`, also notice the last row should be 2 here

```
df['new'] = df['Column_1'].str[-1].fillna(df.Column_1)
df
Out[118]: 
    ID Column_1  new_column  new
0  142   [1, 2]         2.0  2.0
1  144        3         3.0  3.0
2  144        1         1.0  1.0
3  142        1         1.0  1.0
4  142   [1, 3]         3.0  3.0
5  144   [1, 5]         5.0  5.0
6  142        2         NaN  2.0
```